# How to call an external web-service from Joomla

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, joomla

I am going to create a webservice (I think in java) which role is to treat a picture (IN) and to return a result (OUT). I would like to use that web service from my Joomla website.
The process will be :

1- upload of a picture from the website

2- we call the web service to treat the picture

3- we receive the result and display it in a new page

I really don't know how to proceed to do these 3 steps. My first question is : how do I call a web service with Joomla (2.5)?

Thanks

Comment: Is this question specific to Joomla? It seems to me that anyway you call a web service using PHP will work with Joomla.

Comment: So you think I have to do it myself with PHP? Actually I was wondering how to do it with an extension for example. Because I don't know how to do php code with joomla...

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a wrapper which basically means have external websites appear inside where the article/components usually are.

Simply create a new menu item, change the type to "wrapper" and select the URL.

I *think* this is what you are looking for, if not please explain in more detail.

Comment: Thank you Lodder. Yes it should be a good solution, I will try. But I don't think my webservice will return a website, but only a result. Then I have to create a new page displaying this result...

Comment: @Maelkun: maybe you can turn your web-service into a module or component.

Comment: no because the web service may be in another server than the website. But yes, maybe I should create a component dealing with the web service.

Comment: ... or instead of creating a new module, can I just develop in PHP code using Joomla? I don't know how to do it...

Comment: if you want services on Joomla then you have to develop extensions such as modules, component or plugins, you won't be able to integrate it within the core code as it's far too complex and should not be done. Either create an extension for it or use a wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Maelkun,

I tried the example below in Joomla! using Jumi and it worked. If you have php 5.3 you can try with Sourcerer too.

http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.